# Efficient implementation of BPE using priority queue

Tags: string, algorithm, nlp, compression

I think that it is not strictly BPE ([byte pair encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_pair_encoding)), but there is a similar idea applied to strings.

Suppose there are three Chinese words in the dictionary (I will use a huge dictionary like [CEDICT](https://cc-cedict.org/editor/editor.php?handler=Download) for practical use.)

- 我
- 喜欢
- 水果

Then take an input like this below.

我喜欢水果 (I like fruit)

Since Chinese texts are not splitted by white spaces, it's difficult to process.

We can decompose the input string into multiple single characters.

我 喜 欢 水 果

Then lookup new symbol pair at [left, right] and combine them. If the combined word is in the dictionary, we can replace the combined word with a new symbol.

- 我喜
- 喜欢 <- in the dic
- 欢水
- 水果 <- in the dic

We found two new symbols, so the input text becomes

我 喜欢 水果

We should iterate until we cannot find any combined word in the dictionary. In this case, we cannot find a new symbol in the dictionary.

- 我喜欢 水果
- 喜欢水果

It's not difficult to implement this naively but we need to scan adjoining two words many times. Some said we can implement BPE efficiently with a priority queue. I'm not familiar with compression algorithms. I would be grateful if someone could tell me the implementation or useful documentations.

In this method, out of vocabulary words are decomposed into single characters, so we can avoid unknown words problems.

Best regards,

Reference: [Neural Machine Translation of Rare Words with Subword Units](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.07909) He had to start with pre-tokenized words because of computational complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest storing the dictionary as a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) using hash lookups at each level.  This replaces your scans with hash lookups, which are `O(1)`.